# MySQL database to combo box using mysqldatareader in c#.net

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net

MySQL database to combo box using mysqldatareader in c#.net

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from product", connection);
MySqlDataReader dread = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dread.Read())
{
}
```

using mysqldatareader not a mysqldataadapter.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: This is literally 'Do it for me' with little information. 1. We're not here to do your work for you, we're here out of our own choice to help answer questions 2. Can you provide more information on what you're actually trying to achieve? Are you using ASP? Do you want to generate HTML source for a combo-box?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is homework

Comment: This code is using SqlDataAdapter, I want using sqlDataReader  `string query = "select FleetName, FleetID from fleets";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Fleet");
        cmbTripName.DisplayMember =  "FleetName";
        cmbTripName.ValueMember = "FleetID";
        cmbTripName.DataSource = ds.Tables["Fleet"];` This code is using SqlDataAdapter, I want using sqlDataReader

Comment: Fix the question.  There are lots of examples on how to use DataReader.   What have you tried?

Comment: WinForms, WPF, WebForms, or MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow...
Suppost your combox name is cbProducts, and you want fill it with the colum "description" of the query

```
MySQL database to combo box using mysqldatareader in c#.net

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from product", connection);
MySqlDataReader dread = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dread.Read())
{
    cbProducts.Items.Add(dread("description");
}
```

Comment: You've got an unmatched `(` in the last code line, and `dread` is a object, not a method.